# Given an $n-r$ dimensional subspace $H'$ of $k^n$, is there a projection matrix $A$ such that $\ker(A)=H'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove this problem from Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms by Cox et. al.:

> Let $H$ be an $r$-dimensional subspace $H\subset k^n$. Show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between projections of $k^n$ onto $H$ and $n-r$-dimensional subspaces $H'\subset k^n$ which satisfy $H\cap H'=\{0\}$.

My attempt:

A projection onto $H$ can be represented by an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, such that $A^2=A$ and $\text{rank}(A)=r$. We know that $\text{imag}(A)=H$ and $\ker(A)\cap\text{imag}(A)=\{0\}$. So for each $A$, we assign $H'_A=\ker(A)$.

Now since we need to show the correspondence is one-to-one, it remains to show for each $n-r$-dimensional subspace $H'\subset k^n$, we can find a unique projection $A$ such that $\ker(A)=H'$. The uniqueness comes from the condition $A^2=A$. How to show the existence?

I looked at the $2\times 2$ case. The matrix is of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
And it is indeed corresponding to a line $x+by=0$ which is the kernel of this matrix.

But how to show the general case? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the rest of the proof, try to think about linear maps: If $H' \subseteq k^n$ is an $n-r$-dimensional subspace with $H' \cap H = \{0\}$, then it follows that
$$
 \dim(H+H') = \dim(H)+\dim(H')-\dim(H \cap H') = n,
$$
so $H + H' = k^n$. Because $k^n = H + H'$ and $H \cap H' = \{0\}$ we have $k^n = H \oplus H'$. Therefore the map
$$
 q \,\colon k^n = H \oplus H' \to H, \quad h + h' \mapsto h
$$
is well defined and linear. We also have the canonical inclusion $\iota \colon H \hookrightarrow k^n$, $h \mapsto h$, which is also linear.

We can now define $p := \iota \circ q$. Because both $q$ and $\iota$ are linear the same goes for is $p$. Notice that $q \circ \iota = \mathrm{id}_{k^n}$, from which it follows that
$$
 p^2
= \iota \circ q \circ \iota \circ q
= \iota \circ \mathrm{id}_{k^n} \circ q
= p.
$$
Because $\iota$ is injective it follows further that
$$
 \ker(p)
= \ker(\iota \circ q)
= \ker(q)
= H'.
$$
Because $q$ is surjective it follows that
$$
 \mathrm{im}(p)
 = \mathrm{im}(\iota \circ q)
 = \mathrm{im}(\iota)
 = H.
$$
Because $p$ is linear it is given by multiplication with a matrix $A$, which satisfies $A^2 = A$ and $\ker(A) = H'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be $k$-dim vectorsubspace of the $n$-dim vectorspace $V$. Then there's a projektion $p\colon V\to V$ with $ker(p)=U$. You get it by choseing a basis $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ of $U$ take $v_{k+1},\dotsc,v_n$ such that $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ ist a basis of $V$ and define $p$ by $v_i\mapsto 0$ for $i\leq k$, $v_i\mapsto v_i$ for $i>k$.

Answer (score 1):

In one direction to a projection $p:k^n\rightarrow k^n$ assign the subspace $H^\prime=\ker(p)$.

In the other direction, given $H^\prime$ choose a basis $\{v_1,...,v_r,v_{r+1},...,v_n\}$ such that the first $r$ vectors are a basis of $H$ and the last $n-r$ vectors are a basis of $H^\prime$ and define $p:k^n\rightarrow k^n$ as
$$
p(v_i)=v_i\qquad\text{if $i\in\{1,...,r\}$}
$$
and
$$
p(v_i)=0\qquad\text{if $i\in\{r+1,...,n\}$}.
$$
This works since $p$ depends only on $H^\prime$ and not on the chosen basis.